# Bulletproof PHP include from project's root

Tags: php, path, directory, include, hosting

Okay so I don't know if this is a "can't see the forest for the trees" situation but I'm slowly losing my patience on this.

All I want to do is find a way to include files from the project's root, no matter how nested the file, no matter where it's all hosted.

I obviously can't just do absolute paths like "/includes/file.php".

I can't use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] because, as far as the servers where I'm hosting it are concerned, that's the wrong path.

I read about creating a config.php file in the root directory and defining the ROOT_DIR there, but that means I have to include that file RELATIVE in every script, which makes things unstable again. (I don't want every include to break because I moved the file somewhere else)

I can't use constants like **DIR** because it returns the current directory, not the absolute project root.

I tried to set the include path, which doesn't seem to work.

The only "solution" that works for me as of right now: In every file, I define a $root variable and set it to the path that I know is the correct project root.

That can't possibly be the best solution, can it?

There must be an easier way. And the fact that I can't find it drives me crazy.

The root path that works looks something like this:
"/mnt/web10145/dd3/519/5878104319/htdocs/project" (numbers changed)

Using this for includes works just fine. However, calling set_include_path($path) and then including without that path doesn't work.

Please, if anyone knows anything: Every answer is deeply appreciated.
Don't mind pointing out how stupid I am to not have thought about xyz. If it helps me solve the problem it's all good.

Thank you!

Comment: Define a config.php in your root folder. In that define constants for your major subdirectories. Eg: system folder, library, controller, model etc. And then use those constants everywhere in your project

Comment: But I can't use those constants without including the config.php file first. To do that, I have to know how the file im currently looking at is nested. That's exactly what I want to avoid.

Comment: for that, there is **[Autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)**.

Comment: Have you tried [auto prepend](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-automatically-append-prepend/) a script and define the root path there?

Comment: Another way would be to add your `config.php` folder to the include path. You may do this by crafting your [.htaccess](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/php-include-path.html).

Comment: auto_prepend via .htaccess seems to actually solve my problem - thank you very much!
Still I'm wondering: Is this the way it's done by professionals? Because I'm still irritated that there's no clear, no obvious answer to a problem that I assume is rather fundemental. Most of what you can find has more of a work-around character.

Nevertheless, thanks to everyone who took the time to answer!